# Why doesn't Shift + Numlock work, even though there is +NumLock::NumLock?

Tags: autohotkey, num-lock

I have this:

```
NumLock::CapsLock
+NumLock::NumLock
```

However <kbd>Shift + Numlock</kbd> doesn't work, even though I put it in a standalone script, and run in safe mode, with the newest version. Using this works:

```
+NumLock::SetNumLockState, % GetKeyState("Numlock", "T") ? "Off" : "On"
```

It used to work before. Do you know how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why exactly your above code doesn't work. Maybe experimenting with different send modes could reveal the answer, but you can just use [`SetNumLockState`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetNumScrollCapsLockState.htm).

```
NumLock::CapsLock
+NumLock::SetNumLockState, % !GetKeyState("Numlock", "T")
```

`GetKeyState("Numlock", "T")` gets the current logical state of the numlock key, and it's reversed with the `!` operator.

Comment: it doesn't work either. And I put it to a new script, not bundle with other code

Comment: Huh, worked for me. Can you confirm if `+NumLock::MsgBox` works? And what's your AHK version? `MsgBox, % A_AhkVersion`

Comment: Well that explains it, update to the latest version. (Just download the installer from the official site and run it)

Comment: And by latest I mean latest v1 release. Not v2 which is still in alpha stage. Though you could of course switch over to v2 if you so wished. The code above would require a few changes.

Comment: I install 1.1.33.00, it works right after I install it, but then it stop working again. And now it creates fail warnings on my other script as well

Comment: I'd assume you're doing something you shouldn't, because updating most definitely should not break compatibility, or "work and then stop working". What do you do to run AHK scripts? And what do you mean about creating warnings on other script? And if you really can't manage to update, this will work on older versions `+NumLock::SetNumLockState, % GetKeyState("Numlock", "T") ? "Off" : "On"` Here we are just specifying the words `On` and `Off` instead of `1` and `0`.

Comment: to be more precise, it's the files I `#include` to the main script ([image](https://i.imgur.com/gKgWZxU.png)). You can see that the lines are incorrect - there is no way that I put too many `Return` consecutively. *What do you do to run AHK scripts?* I just double click on it.

Comment: That's just because the [`#Warn`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Warn.htm) directive (which gives warnings for common mistakes) was updated to give warnings for unreachable code. Assuming you didn't find some bug, you just have redundant `Return`s there, which result in some unreachable code. Either just click OK to the warnings, fix the mistake(s), set the script to ignore those types of mistakes (instructions in `#Warn`s documentation), or remove the whole `#Warn` directive to receive no warnings. And double clicking .ahk is good. Just made sure because I've seen some weird setups

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So... do you have any idea why `+numlock` doesn't work?

Comment: Not really. Seems to work perfectly fine on my end, and you also said it worked, but then somehow it stopped working? Don't really know what could be up with that.